Creating a dynamic date, so that i dont have to manually input the date next year
I have a SQL query as shown below. I would like to have dynamic dates for the current and previous financial years, so that when I run the code in the future, I don't have to manually update the commented sections. I appreciate your help with this.

    SELECT '2023/2024' AS FY_YEAR_SNAPSHOT, --I want to make 2023/2024 as dynamic
           1 AS COUNT
    FROM TABLE
    WHERE TO_DATE('2023-07-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
        BETWEEN EFEC_STRT_DT AND EFEC_END_DT -- '2023-07-01' to be dynamic

    UNION ALL

    SELECT '2022/2023' AS FY_YEAR_SNAPSHOT, -2022/2023 to be dynamic
        1 AS COUNT
    FROM TABLE
    WHERE TO_DATE('2022-07-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
        BETWEEN EFEC_STRT_DT AND EFEC_END_DT --2022-07-01 to be dynamic.


I want to make 2023/2024 as dynamic What does this mean exactly?  Will it always be "the previous calendar year, followed by a slash, followed by the current calendar year"?

'2023-07-01' to be dynamic What does this mean exactly?  Is this the start of a fiscal year, or something?  Will the date always be July first, and only the year changes?  Is it always "The most recent July first before today"?  What if today IS July first?

At what point in the year do you want to start showing the next value? July 1, or some point maybe a little after?

Hi John, Yes the first select statement snapshot between effective EFEC_STRT_DT  and EFEC_END_DT has to be start of this year Fy year which is 2023-07-01 and i have to give a period name, and i have called it as 2023/2024, but i am ok to call anything if it suits according to the code. Same goes for the second select statment where the Fy year snap shot has to be last year Fy start date which is 2022-07-01. Let me know if this clarifies your question

Hi Joel, all i want is when i run the code next year same time, the first select statment to_date has to become('2024-07-01') and the 2024/2025 as FY_YEAR_SNAPSHOT.
And for the second select statment the to_date has to be '2023/2024' AS FY_YEAR_SNAPSHOT
WHERE TO_DATE('2023-07-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN EFEC_STRT_DT AND EFEC_END_DT.
Let me know if this clarifies your question

hi @CK-P what should be the data if we run the query post 01-JUL-2024 and before 31-DEC-2024

Assuming your financial year starts on 1st July each year then you can use:
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -6))
       || '/' || EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 6)) AS FY_YEAR_SNAPSHOT,
       1 AS COUNT
FROM table_name
WHERE ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -6), 'YYYY'), 6) 
     BETWEEN EFEC_STRT_DT AND EFEC_END_DT
UNION ALL
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -18))
       || '/' || EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -6)) AS FY_YEAR_SNAPSHOT,
       1 AS COUNT
FROM table_name
WHERE ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -18), 'YYYY'), 6)
      BETWEEN EFEC_STRT_DT AND EFEC_END_DT

or, using a JOIN to a sub-query factoring clause (or CTE) to only query the table once:
WITH financial_years (fy_start_date, fy_year_snapshot) AS (
  SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -6), 'YYYY'), 6),
         EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -6))
         || '/' || EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 6))
  FROM   DUAL
UNION ALL
  SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -18), 'YYYY'), 6),
         EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -18))
         || '/' || EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -6))
  FROM   DUAL
)
SELECT fy_year_snapshot,
       1 AS count
FROM   table_name t
       INNER JOIN financial_years fy
       ON (fy.fy_start_date BETWEEN t.efec_strt_dt AND t.efec_end_dt)

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (efec_strt_dt, efec_end_dt) AS
SELECT DATE '2022-07-01', DATE '2023-07-01' - INTERVAL '1' SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-07-01', DATE '2024-07-01' - INTERVAL '1' SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-07-01', DATE '2025-07-01' - INTERVAL '1' SECOND FROM DUAL;

Both output:



FY_YEAR_SNAPSHOT
COUNT




2023/2024
1


2022/2023
1



fiddle

It is not quite clear what is your refference date (is it SYSDATE or something else). Here is the code for generating the dates depending on refference date.
WITH
    tbl (ID, REFFERENCE_DATE) AS
        ( Select 1, DATE '2023-06-30' From Dual Union All 
          Select 2, DATE '2023-07-01' From Dual Union All 
          Select 3, DATE '2024-09-30' From Dual
        )
Select    ID,
          REFFERENCE_DATE, 
          Case  When EXTRACT(Month From REFFERENCE_DATE) <= 6
                Then To_Char(EXTRACT(Year From REFFERENCE_DATE) - 1) || '/' || To_Char(EXTRACT(Year From REFFERENCE_DATE))
          Else  To_Char(EXTRACT(Year From REFFERENCE_DATE)) || '/' || To_Char(EXTRACT(Year From REFFERENCE_DATE) + 1)
          End "FY_YEAR_SNAPSHOT",
          Case  When EXTRACT(Month From REFFERENCE_DATE) <= 6
                Then To_Date(To_Char(EXTRACT(Year From REFFERENCE_DATE) - 1) || '-07-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
          Else  To_Date(To_Char(EXTRACT(Year From REFFERENCE_DATE)) || '-07-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
          End  "FY_START"
From      tbl

/*   R e s u l t :
        ID REFFERENCE_DATE FY_YEAR_SNAPSHOT    FY_START
---------- --------------- ------------------- --------
         1 30.06.23        2022/2023           01.07.22
         2 01.07.23        2023/2024           01.07.23
         3 30.09.24        2024/2025           01.07.24
*/

NOTE: The above Case expressions (or any other) could be used in Where clause too. From your sample code I assume you have defined EFEC_STRT_DT and EFEC_END_DT that are unique. If that is so you can have the Where clause (instead of Between) like this:
... ... ...
Where     Case  When EXTRACT(Month From REFFERENCE_DATE) <= 6
                Then To_Date(To_Char(EXTRACT(Year From REFFERENCE_DATE) - 1) || '-07-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
          Else  To_Date(To_Char(EXTRACT(Year From REFFERENCE_DATE)) || '-07-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
          End = EFEC_STRT_DATE

Just apply your REFFERENCE_DATE ... Refference dates in this answer are used for simulations of the query results if the query runs on those dates (SYSDATE).

you can use the below based on your requirement
If you require based on calender year
with dymanic_year as (select to_number(to_char(sysdate,'YYYY')) year_number from dual)
    SELECT to_char(year_number-1)||'/'||to_Char(year_number)
      
      AS FY_YEAR_SNAPSHOT, --I want to make 2023/2024 as dynamic
               1 AS COUNT
        FROM TABLE_name,dymanic_year
        WHERE TO_DATE(to_char(year_number-1)||'-07-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
            BETWEEN EFEC_STRT_DT AND EFEC_END_DT -- '2023-07-01' to be dynamic

        UNION ALL

        SELECT to_char(year_number-2)||'/'||to_char(year_number-1) AS FY_YEAR_SNAPSHOT, --2022/2023 to be dynamic
            1 AS COUNT
        FROM TABLE_name,dymanic_year
        WHERE TO_DATE(to_char(year_number-2)||'-07-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
            BETWEEN EFEC_STRT_DT AND EFEC_END_DT --2022-07-01 to be dynamic.

If you require based on Financial year
    with subset as (
      select  to_number(
                to_char(sysdate,'YYYY')
             ) year_number
      from   dual
    ),
    dynamic_year as
      (select case when to_number(to_char(sysdate,'MM')) >=07
      then year_number +1 else year_number end as year_number from subset)
      
    SELECT to_char(year_number-1)||'/'||to_Char(year_number)
             AS FY_YEAR_SNAPSHOT, --I want to make 2023/2024 as dynamic
           1 AS COUNT
    FROM TABLE_name,dynamic_year
    WHERE TO_DATE(to_char(year_number-1)||'-07-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
            BETWEEN EFEC_STRT_DT AND EFEC_END_DT -- '2023-07-01' to be dynamic
    UNION ALL
    SELECT to_char(year_number-2)||'/'||to_char(year_number-1) AS FY_YEAR_SNAPSHOT, --2022/2023 to be dynamic
           1 AS COUNT
    FROM TABLE_name,dynamic_year
    WHERE TO_DATE(to_char(year_number-2)||'-07-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
            BETWEEN EFEC_STRT_DT AND EFEC_END_DT --2022-07-01 to be dynamic.


This is wrong. When the SYSDATE is 2024-07-01 (the start of the OP's next financial year) then the years should be 2024/2025 and 2023/2024 (but this would give 2023/2024 and 2022/2023) fiddle

included the case for financial year
